# categorised multidimensional string and filter

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional string as follows

```
$string = '(car)hyundai|(car)bmw|(car)tesla|(bus)abc|(bus)cde|(cycle)are|(cyele)dyd|......'
```

I want to categorized the items in vehicles (car, bus, cycle..) and create a radio button based on the vehicles

```
<input type = "radio" value="car"> 
<input type = "radio" value="bus">
```

and do an onclick event to display the value for each categories
So If I click car, then all the car values needs to be displayed (e.g. hyunday, bmw, tesla)

so Far I have done this

```
 $mainData = explode('|', $string);
 $data1 = [];
 $category =[];
 $subcategory =[];
 $i=0;
 foreach($mainData as $data){
     $data2 = explode(')', $data);
     $data1[$data2[0]][] = $data2[1];
   }  

   foreach ($data1 as $data3 => $dataContents) {
     $datas[$data3] = array_unique($dataContents);
     array_push($category,  $data3);
     array_push($subcategory, $datas[$data3]);                   
   }
```

I can separate the data but couldn't filter the data. Any idea would be highly appreciated

Comment: I have to ask... where does the string come from? It seems like it's in a very poor format. Can't you get it in a better way, like json, xml or even a query string? I don't know how you want the data to be parsed, but your script produces this: https://3v4l.org/ct4If which doesn't really look correct (I assume?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = '(car)Hyundai|(car)BMW|(car)Tesla|(bus)Madina|(bus)Alsa|(cycle)BMX';
```

Split the `$string` into an array of `$vehicles` by the function `explode`:

```php
$vehicles = explode('|', $string); // ["(car)Hyundai","(car)BMW","(car)Tesla","(bus)Madina","(bus)Alsa","(cycle)BMX"]
```

Loop through `$vehicles` array. Take the type of vehicle *(car, bus...)* and their marks by exploding again, but this time with `(`. and get rid of the `(` in the begining by using `ltrim` or just `substr`. Store those `$vehicles` in an array `$res`, grouped by type.

```php
$res = [];
foreach ($vehicles as $vehicle) {
    [$type, $mark] = explode(')', $vehicle);
    $type = ltrim($type, '('); #substr($type, 1);
    $res[$type][] = $mark;
}
```

```
Array
(
    [car] => Array
        (
            [0] => Hyundai
            [1] => BMW
            [2] => Tesla
        )

    [bus] => Array
        (
            [0] => Madina
            [1] => Alsa
        )

    [cycle] => Array
        (
            [0] => BMX
        )

)
```

### Demonstration:

```php
function category($value)
{
    return "<label><input onclick=hide('$value') name='category' type='radio' value='$value'/>$value<label>";
}
function sub_category($type, $name)
{
    return "<label><input name='$type' type='radio' value='$name'/>$name<label>";
}
$categories = array_map("category", array_keys($res));
echo implode('<br>', $categories);
foreach ($res as $cat => $sub_cat) {
    echo "<fieldset class='field $cat' style='background-color: #eeeeee;width: 50%;'>";
    echo "<legend>$cat</legend>";
    foreach ($sub_cat as $vehicle) {
        echo sub_category($cat, $vehicle);
    }
    echo "</fieldset>";
}

echo "<script>
        function hideAll(){
            document.querySelectorAll('.field').forEach(e=>e.style.visibility='hidden');
        }
        
        function hide(subCat){
            hideAll();
            document.querySelector('.field.'+subCat).style.visibility='visible';
        }
    </script>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method to convert the string into a reasonable array.

```php
$string = '(car)hyundai|(car)bmw|(car)tesla|(bus)abc|(bus)cde|(cycle)are|(cyele)dyd';
$requiredArr = [];
$dataArr = explode('|', $string);
foreach ($dataArr as $data){
    $dataSubArr = explode(')', ltrim($data, '('));
    $vehicle = $dataSubArr[0];
    $vType = $dataSubArr[1];
    $requiredArr[$vehicle][] = $vType;
}
```

And one way of generating the radio input element is

```
foreach ($requiredArr as $vehicle => $type){
    echo sprintf('<input type = "radio" value="%s">', $vehicle);
}
```

I hope you are using `ajax` to get additional data when a user clicks on the radio button.